# jackrabbit oak repository integration with spring framework

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jackrabbit-oak

I have a web application running on tomcat and using spring framework. I also have jackrabbit oak libraries embedded in project.
I can get jackrabbit repository with java code like this:

```
new Jcr(new Oak(ns)).createRepository();
```

but I want to define my repository in a repository.xml file and then  put it somewhere and instantiate it with spring xml files, so I can customize various things like ExternalIdentityProvider in my repository.
Something like this I think:

```
<bean id="repository" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.repository.RepositoryImpl" 
references="repository.xml"/>
```

but I don't know how I should define this repository in spring. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

just use it like any other library:

1. put some variables in your `application.properties`
2. use Java config (XML config is not the most robust one)
3. access those variables using your favourite way
4. build your `ns` object using those variables
5. register the outcome of `new Jcr(new Oak(ns)).createRepository()` as a `Bean` that uses the newly created `ns` object - [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-annotations#configuration) should help you

and that should do the trick :)